# How to replace the deprecated fold function on KeyedStreams

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

The `fold` function on Flink's `KeyedStreams` is deprecated. The `aggregate` function is private and furthermore limited to some predefined aggregation-types.

A nice aggregate implementation is available on `WindowedStreams`. So what I could do is to define a `GlobalWindow` with some kind of `AlwaysOnElementTrigger` (which fires on every single element). That somehow feels wrong to me but I can't see the downsides.

My question: Do I have to live with the deprecation-warning or is the `GlobalWindow` workaround just a little ugly but does what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `RichFlatMapFunction` or `KeyedProcessFunction` feels like a more straightforward approach.

Comment: Thanks David. I'll give it a try.